# Graphing integer function $f(x) = [\sin^{-1}x]$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I have few difficulties when drawing inverse trigonometric functions graph. I am unable to draw the graph of $[\sin^{-1}x]$; the [$\cdot$] (the brackets] denote *the greatest integer function* of $\sin^{-1}x$. I am confused whether  to take integers on x axis or angles in radians on $x$-axis .

I would be grateful if someone could guide me in drawing the above function’s graph.

Comment: Remember that arcsine takes a ratio and returns an angle

Comment: I got that but I am unable to understand one thing . When we are drawing the graph of greatest integer function of sin inverse x . Should we take integers on y axis and angles on x axis or are supposed to take +1 -1 and other values on x axis

Comment: If you prepend a backslash character to the trigonometric function's name, LaTeX/MathJax will treat is as a symbol and render it in upright font with appropriate spacing instead of a series of italic letters, looking like a multiplication of a bunch of variables. Please compare `a sin x` → $a sin x$ vs. `a\sin x` → $a\sin x$. (More hints at [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our  [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greatest integer function returns the greatest integer less than or equal to its argument. In your case $[\sin^{-1}(x)]$, the G.I.N.T (greatest integer function) takes **angles as input** but the angles vary based on the value of $x$ which is a **real value**. So the x-axis is for **real values between -1 and 1**.

So for the input to your G.I.N.T, we have to consider the *range* of sine inverse as those values are inputted in the argument. Because we know
$$\sin^{-1}:[-1,1]\to[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
and $\frac{\pi}{2}>1$, we have to consider the following *domains* (values of $x$) separately:
$$[-1,-\sin(1)),[-\sin(1),0),[0,\sin(1)),[\sin(1),1]$$
You can obtain these partitions yourself by trying to find where the argument to G.I.N.T becomes an integer and also keeping in mind the range of the sine inverse function.
In the first domain, $\sin^{-1}(x)\in[\frac{-\pi}{2}-1)$, so its G.I.N.T is -2 here. 
In the second domain, $\sin^{-1}(x)\in[-1,0)$, so its G.I.N.T is -1 here.
...

Assuming you can do the other 2, you get:

[image]